# Using MessageFormat, group decimal places

Tags: java, messageformat

I am using MessageFormat. The current pattern is:

```
{0,number,#,###.######}
```

For `0.123456` it gives me

```
0.123456
```

which is expected. However I want to group the decimal places so that the display is

```
0.123 456
```

I would also like trailing zeros, so for `0.1234` the display would be

```
0.123 400
```

I can't seem to find the correct custom pattern for this

Comment: And, yes, I could write a parser for a ```float```, generate the number with the spacing, then use {0} to show the number.

Answer (score 1):

For the trailing zeros you could replace the `#` with `0` in the decimal places like `"{0,number,#,###.000000}"`
See [DecimalFormat#Special Pattern Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
0   Number  Yes Digit
#   Number  Yes Digit, zero shows as absent
```

Comment: For some reason that page did not show up for me in Google :-( Thanks

Comment: Just look for `java  8 decimalformat` with Google

Comment: Yes, but I was looking up MessageFormat. It should be the same for any computer language which supports it (Java, PHP, etc)

Comment: for the decimal grouping I couldn't found anything useful. 
So here is some regex fu. Hope it helps

`String formatted =  MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#,##0.000000}", 12.1234);`
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+[.]\\d{3})(\\d{3})");`
`Matcher m = p.matcher(formatted);`
`if (m.matches()) {`
`String correct = m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2);`
`System.out.println(correct);`
`}`